# Is it possible to assume that an étale neighborhood is connected?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, limits-and-colimits

I am new to étale topology (though I've seen Grothendieck's sites before).

Let $S:=\mathcal{O}^\textrm{sh}_{X,x}$ be the strict local ring of a point $x$ of a scheme $X=\operatorname{Spec}R$ (over a nonalgebraically closed field).
Let $C$ and $B$ be $R$-algebras and $f_S\colon B\otimes_R S\to C\otimes_R S$ an injective homomorphism of $S$-algebras.
By http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04HX, we have $S=\operatorname{colim}_{(U,u)}\mathcal{O}(U)$,
where the colimit is over all étale neighbourhoods of the point $x$ in $X$.

Can I deduce that $f_S$ arises from an injective homomorphism $f_U\colon B\otimes_R \mathcal{O}(U)\to C\otimes_R \mathcal{O}(U)$ for some étale neighbourhood $(U,u)$?

I think such a (possibly non-injective) $f_U$ should exist. Is there is a reason that I can suppose that $U$ is connected in order to deduce injectivity?

Comment: Please more precise with your hypotheses: are $B$ and $C$ finitely presented over $R$, and is $R$ noetherian?  (Not clear why you mention a field, as that doesn't play a role in the question.) If finitely presented then by standard limit methods $f$ "spreads out" to some such $U$ and by faithful flatness considerations the localization of $f_U$ at $u$ is injective.  If $R$ is noetherian (so $S$ is) then $\ker f_U$ is finitely generated, so injectivity after localizing at $u$ would "spread out" over a Zariski neighborhood of $u$. What are you precise hypotheses?

Comment: A general scheme is not locally connected, but for most issues where connectedness is useful one can either reduce to the noetherian case (which is locally connected) or else to the case of a local base (which is connected), often "spreading out" conclusions from the latter via finite presentation considerations. Keep in mind crazy rings like an infinite direct product $R$ of copies of a field $k$, for which all points apart from the obvious "clopen" $k$-points from the factors have *no* Zariski-connected open neighborhood.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of these "spreading out" results and searching gave me some references. I can suppose that $R$ is a Noetherian local ring, and that $B$ and $C$ are of finite presentation over $R$. By EGA IV Thm. 8.5.2 there exists $f_U\colon B\otimes_R \mathcal{O}(U)\to C\otimes_R \mathcal{O}(U)$ for some étale neighbourhood $(U,u)$. By Cor. 8.5.8 $f_U$ is injective. Can I pass to the image of $U\rightarrow X$ (and its connected component) in order to assume that $U$ is a Zariski open neighborhood (and further connected)?

Comment: You have misread the statement of 8.5.8 since those $O(U)$-algebras are not finitely presented as *modules*. It is also meaningless to pass to the image of $U$ in $X$ since you cannot expect to "descend" $f_U$ to such a neighborhood; forget about the Zariski topology of $X$ for these purposes.  You have not given the motivation for your question, so I have no idea why you are attached to trying to pass to Zariski opens in $X$ or to connectedness in the base. Please give motivation for your question and it will then be clearer what you really need.